# Is this scala type bounding the same as this java type bounding?

Tags: java, scala, generics

What, if any, are the differences between these two? Are that equivalent or is one subtly more powerful than I realize?

Scala type bounding

```
class AnimalHandler[A <: Animal, F <: Food] {
  def getFood(a: A): F = { ... }
}
```

Java type bounding

```
class AnimalHanlder<A extends Animal, F extends Food> {
  public F getFood(A a) { ... }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK: Scala is in that way stronger that you can specify upper and aswell lowerbounds: taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/scala-generics-part-1-scala-type-bounds): `class Parking[A >: Bicycle <: Vehicle]`

Comment: These examples both compile to the same bytecode, but I wouldn't expect e.g. inference to work the same way in both languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare byte code generated from `AnimalHandler` in Scala and Java here: https://www.diffchecker.com/HyAuDYo5

`class AnimalHandler[A <: Animal, F <: Food]` in Scala will be seen in Java as `class AnimalHanlder<A extends Animal, F extends Food>` and vice versa.

`A <: B` means that `A` is a subtype of `B`. In Java the only way to create a subtype is with inheritance

```
class Cow extends Animal
class Grasp extends Food
new AnimalHandler[Cow, Grasp]
```

(that's why keyword `extends` is used instead of `<:`) but in Scala there are many ways to create subtypes:

```
val cow: Cow = new Cow
val grasp: Grasp = new Grasp
new AnimalHandler[cow.type, grasp.type]
```

or

```
type Cow <: Animal
type Grasp <: Food
new AnimalHandler[Cow, Grasp]
```

or

```
trait CowLike
trait GraspLike
new AnimalHandler[Animal with CowLike, Food with GraspLike]
```

or

```
trait Animal {
  type F <: Food
}
trait Food
class Grasp extends Food
class Cow extends Animal {
  override type F <: Grasp
}
new AnimalHandler[Cow, Cow#F]
```

or

```
val cow: Cow = new Cow
new AnimalHandler[cow.type, cow.F]
```

or

```
trait Animal 
class Cow extends Animal
trait Food
class Grasp extends Food
trait GetFoodTypeclass[A <: Animal] {
  type F <: Food
}
object GetFoodTypeclass {
  implicit val cowGrasp: GetFoodTypeclass[Cow] { type F = Grasp } = null 
}
def foo[A <: Animal](implicit getFood: GetFoodTypeclass[A]) = {
  new AnimalHandler[A, getFood.F]
}
```

So type system of Scala is more powerful that the one of Java and that's the reason why subtyping (`<:`) is more powerful than subclassing (`extends`).

Also in Scala you can have lower bound

```
trait Animal
trait Mammal extends Animal
class Cow extends Mammal
class CowHandler[A >: Cow <: Animal]
new CowHandler[Mammal]
```

but in Java lower bounds can be used only with wildcards

```
interface Animal {}
interface Mammal extends Animal {}
class AnimalHanlder<A extends Animal> {}
void handle(AnimalHanlder<? super Mammal> handler) {}
```

Also in Scala you can specify variance.

Comment: Thank you for the examples and explanation. This was very illuminating

Answer (score 3):

It is. You can more or less read `<:` as `extends` and `>:` as `super`.

I'm usually not a big fan of symbols, but in this case I like the parallel with the familiar `<` and `>` operators: the side with the smallest "mouth" is "smaller". In the case of types, `A <: B` means that `A` is a sub-type of `B` (it `extends`, it's more specific).

Comment: Actually, they are `<` and `>` but with `:` added so that it won't be confusing to parser (and reader). If you think of types as sets then super-types/super-sets are "bigger" as they contain all values from their sub-types=sub-sets, while sub-classes/sub-sets contain only fraction of values of super-type/super-set so they are smaller. So it's exactly `<` and `>` in partial ordering.

Comment: This is a fantastic way of associating the symbols!